# Eclipse Helios 3.6.2 won't create generated java files in android project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have Eclipse Helios 3.6.2
latest android sdk tools 22
and latest adt 22.0

when I create a new android application project the gen folder is just empty.

Comment: ok well firstly, this is not my answer.
secondly, I didn't find the answer till I got it by myself no thank you, of course.
the answer is when you update to sdk tools 22 you also need to install android SDK build tool.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me quite a number of time. Here are what I did

1. Make sure there's no errors in any of your xml (in the res folder). Eclipse won't create the R file if there's error with your xml
2. Refresh and clean the project

Comment: I found it, thank you anyways.
the answer to my question is when you update to sdk tools 22 you also need to install android SDK build tool.